# como eliminar un directorio con php?

Tags: php

deseo eliminar un directorio, pero cuando ejecuto la funcion ésta me devuelve un mensaje de de error interno (ruta_de_mi_archivo.php 500 (Internal Server Error)).

cuando creo una carpeta con php lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
mkdir($ruta_dir, 0777, true);
```

y la función que utilizo para eliminar el directorio es la siguiente:

```
Eliminar_Dir($eliminar_ruta);

        function Eliminar_Dir($eliminar_ruta) {
            if (is_dir($eliminar_ruta)) {
                $gestor = opendir($eliminar_ruta);
                while (($archivo = readdir($gestor)) !== false) {
                    $ruta_completa = $eliminar_ruta . "/" . $archivo;
                    if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != ".." && $archivo != ".DS_Store") {
                        if (unlink($ruta_completa)) {
                            Eliminar_Dir($eliminar_ruta);
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($gestor);
            }
        }

        if(@rmdir($eliminar_ruta)){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

tal vez tengas error en permisos que no se cambian al 0777 intenta poner debajo de eso
mkdir($ruta_dir,0777,true);

esto
chmod($ruta_dir,0777,true);
solo para descartar ese problema

tambien pon "\ \" ya que en windows no agarra solo /

Comment: lo estoy haciendo para un sitio web, intentare con chmod($ruta_dir,0777,true), a ver como me va y te comento, gracias

Answer (score 0):

he solucionado mi problema de la siguiente manera:

```
$ruta = $_POST['eliminar_ruta'];
$dir_eliminar = scandir($ruta);//agrego todo el contenido del directorio seleccionado en un arreglo con scandir

//recorro el arreglo y elimino todos sus archivos para posterior eliminar la carpeta
foreach($dir_eliminar as $llave => $file){
   if(!is_dir($file) && $file!="." && $file!=".."){
      $del_ruta= $ruta.'/'.$file;
      if(unlink($del_ruta)){}
   }
}

//aca elimino la carpeta
if(rmdir($ruta)){
   echo 1;
}else{
   echo 0;
}
```